# iOS 9 play audio in silent mode but keep other app's music playback running

Tags: ios, audio

I have some warning sounds in my app but I really need background music (e.g. Spotify) to keep running in the background. I solved this by

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:nil];
```

However, in silent mode my `AVAudioPlayer`s are muted but the sound is crucial, even in silent mode. I read about `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound` ignoring silent mode but it does not, at least not on iOS9.

Any other possibilities? Oh and please waste your time by saying things like "I would hate this as a user", "isn't it called SILENT mode", ... this is a programming page, not a philosophy class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Audio Session Category **AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient** will obey the Ring/Silent switch as stated in the documentation -

> AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient
>   The category for an app in which sound playback is nonprimary—that is, your app can be used successfully with the sound turned off...
>
> ... Your audio is silenced by screen locking and by the Silent switch (called the Ring/Silent switch on iPhone).

I suggest trying a better suited category with mixing options like -

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback 
                                 withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers 
                                       error:nil];
```

**AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback** category will ignore the silent switch as mentioned in documentation -

> When using this category, your app audio continues with the Silent switch set to silent or when the screen locks.

Comment: Does this still work in iOS 9? When I'm trying this on the GM, it no longer works and it's only vibrating.

Comment: It doesn't work for me either: iPhone 8, software version 13.7

Answer (score 0):

I put code in a button action for play audio :

that's work for newer iOS version too (I'm using that in iOS 12)

( play background music in silent mode and in same time play audio in your app when click button together )

```
import AVFoundation

var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

@IBAction func btnAudioClickableAct(_ sender: Any) {

    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    try!audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, with: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.mixWithOthers)

    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "activityAudio", ofType: "mp3") {

        let filePath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:path)
        audioPlayer = try! AVAudioPlayer.init(contentsOf: filePath as URL)
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer.play()

    }

}
```